# Change cmap transition points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, visualization, heatmap

Is there a way to change the transition values of a continuous colormap (cmap) in matplotlib? I want to use "vlag" to color a heatmap, however my values only typically range from 0 to 0.6 (instead of 0-1). I could renormalize my data or use vmin & vmax, however I was curious if there was a way to set transition points for vlag between 0-1. There are three colors in vlag (blue, white, and red). Having set transition points will allow for an apples to apples comparison between different heatmaps.

Comment: Hi @JohanC, BoundaryNorm creates categorical colors from continuous data. I want to retain the continuous color just change the transition points. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Please see https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the colormap only contains few colors, a [BoundaryNorm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) lets you specify the transition points.

For a colormap with a smooth range of colors, a [TwoSlopeNorm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html) lets you move the spots where the transitions start happening.

```py
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
import seaborn as sns  # for the 'vlag' colormap
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = np.sin(x)**2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
scat0 = axs[0].scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap='vlag')
axs[0].set_title('default norm')
plt.colorbar(scat0, ax=axs[0])

norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0., vcenter=0.3, vmax=1)
scat1 = axs[1].scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap='vlag', norm=norm)
axs[1].set_title('TwoSlopeNorm')
plt.colorbar(scat1, ax=axs[1])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example of TwoSlopeNorm]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you @JohanC!, TwoSlopeNorm is exactly what I was looking for, also the comment by Jody was also very helpful!